# Copy all unprotected cells in Sheet to another sheet and keep position

Tags: vba, excel

Sheet 1 in workbook A contains some cells with formulas that are protected and some cells that are used to enter data that are unprotected. There are multiple files that uses this structure.

I have now updated the formulas in a template file that use the same structure. 
What I want to do is to copy all unprotected cells and move them to the same place in the new file.

Let’s say the range is A1:R99 and I have unprotected cells in B1:B99 and G1:G99 (multiple different places in real file so entering all different ranges would take a long time) Then I want to copy B1:B99 to the same place in the new file. 
Hope there is a better way to do this than to enter every range manually!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide the code you got. If you don't have any, start small and do it step by step. Accessing different workbooks, looping over cells, checking cell properties etc.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the data in 'Sheet1' and if you want to copy all the unprotected cells to a new sheet, lets say 'Sheet2' in the same location as they were in 'Sheet1', then

```
Sub Foo()

If Sheets("Sheet1").ProtectContents = True Then

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    For i = 1 To 99
        For j = 1 To 18
            If Cells(i, j).Locked = False Then
                a = Cells(i, j).Value
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
                Cells(i, j).Value = a
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End If

End Sub
```